# Python interpolate throws no errors - but also does nothing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I am trying some DataFrame manipulation in Pandas that I have learnt. The dataset that I am playing with is from the [EY Data Science Challenge](http://www.ey.com/au/en/careers/students/ey-data-science-challenge).

This first part may be irrelevant but just for context - I have gone through and set some indexes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# loading the main dataset
df_main = pd.read_csv(filename)

'''Sorting Indexes'''
# getting rid of the id column
del df_main['id']

# sorting values by LOCATION and GENDER columns
# setting index to LOCATION (1st tier) then GENDER (2nd tier) and then re- 
#sorting
df_main = df_main.sort_values(['LOCATION','TIME'])
df_main = df_main.set_index(['LOCATION','TIME']).sort_index()
```

The problem I have is with the missing values - I have decided that columns 7 ~ 18 can be interpolate because a lot of the data is very consistent year by year.

So I made a simple function to take in a list of columns and apply the interpolate function for each column.

```
'''Missing Values'''
x = df_main.groupby("LOCATION")

def interpolate_columns(list_of_column_names):
    for column in list_of_column_names:
        df_main[column] = x[column].apply(lambda x: x.interpolate(how = 'linear'))

interpolate_columns( list(df_main.columns[7:18]) )
```

However, the problem I am getting is one of the columns (Access to electricity (% of urban population with access) [1.3_ACCESS.ELECTRICITY.URBAN]) seems to not be interpolating when all the other columns are interpolated successfully.

I get no errors thrown when I run the function, and it is not trying to interpolate backwards either.

Any ideas regarding why this problem is occurring?

EDIT: I should also mention that the column in question was missing the same number of values - and in the same rows - as many of the other columns that interpolated successfully.

Comment: without knowing how your data looks like: have you checked that your column in question is actually included in the processed range of columns[7:18] (simple print statement)?

Comment: Yes, I have just done that now, and the column that I am having trouble with is column number 10. The dataset I am using can be found here (http://www.ey.com/au/en/careers/students/ey-data-science-challenge) the columns I am trying to interpolate are from J ~ T in the "train.csv" file.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the data more closely, it seems like interpolate was not working on some columns because I was missing data at the **first rows** of the group in the groupby object.